# awk help for getting fields

Tags: awk

I have field like

```
a_b_c_d
```

I want as the output a b c_d, this query wont work for this

```
awk -F"_" <file> | '{print $1,$2,$3}'
```

Since it will only print a b c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
awk -F"_" -f <file> '{ print $1" "$2" "$3"_"$4 }'
```

In other words,

```
$echo a_b_c_d | awk -F"_" '{ print $1" "$2" "$3"_"$4 }'      
a b c_d
```

The code in the brackets means

- print the first match
- print space
- print the second match
- print space
- ...

Comment: Minor detail, but you can just do `awk -F_` instead of `awk -F"_"`.

Comment: You can golf it further with: awk -F_ '{ print $1, $2, $3"_"$4 }'